# Is there a way to get the possible arguments for a command in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I've recently been learning Node.js and I've been making a tool that lets you enter a bash command name and it will list the possible arguments for that command, similar to `man`. Is there a way to find possible arguments for commands through Node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't specific to Node: there isn't a *universal* way to get the arguments for any command, at all.

The `man` command does not "find out" information about programs, it simply renders "manual pages" which have been written by humans to describe them. If your system has a manual page for the command, you can retrieve it; if it does not (or the manual page is wrong), you would have to know about the program in order to write it.

Many programs will also display some summary information when passed an option like "--help", but that's just something the authors of individual commands choose to implement, and cannot be relied on.

To prove this to yourself, think about your own program: it has an argument that should be the name of a command; if I'm writing my own version of the program, where would it find the information about your command?